# UWP: exception when setting a property just after setting another one

Tags: windows, xaml, exception, uwp, inotifypropertychanged

I think I got a threading problem in my UWP app.
I want to do a very simple thing:

- a UI with 2 numeric fields;
- if a numeric value is typed in `field1`, I want `field2` to be set with a ratio of `field1` (example: `field2 = ratio * field1`).

I am using `x:Bind` and `TextChanging` events. For unknown reasons, I wasn't able in the XAML to "call" the `TextChanging` event without having an exception at startup. Therefore, I am using the `Loaded` event.

Here's my model class, simply called `MyModel`:

```cs
public class MyModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private readonly uint r1 = 3;

    private uint _field1;
    public uint Field1
    {
        get { return this._field1; }
        set
        {
            this.Set(ref this._field1, value);

            if (value == 0)
            {
                Field2 = 0;
            }
            else
            {
                Field2 = value * r1;
            }
        }
    }

    private uint _field2;
    public uint Field2
    {
        get { return this._field2; }
        set
        {
            this.Set(ref this._field2, value);
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void RaisedPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName]string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    protected bool Set<T>(ref T storage, T value, [CallerMemberName]string propertyName = null)
    {
        if (Equals(storage, value))
        {
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            storage = value;
            this.RaisedPropertyChanged(propertyName);
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

My ViewModel:

```cs
public class MyModelViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public MyModel MyModel { get; set; }

    public MyModelViewModel()
    {
        // Initialisation de notre page
        this.MyModel = new MyModel()
        {
            Field1 = 0
        };
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

my code behind (I'm filtering the input to avoid a cast exception):

```cs
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    public MyModelViewModel ViewModel { get; set; } = new MyModelViewModel();

    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void InitField1(object sender, Windows.UI.Xaml.RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        field1.TextChanging += field1_TextChanging;
    }

    private void InitField2(object sender, Windows.UI.Xaml.RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        field2.TextChanging += field2_TextChanging;
    }

    private void field1_TextChanging(TextBox sender, TextBoxTextChangingEventArgs args)
    {
        var error = errorTextBlock;
        error.Visibility = Windows.UI.Xaml.Visibility.Collapsed;

        Regex regex = new Regex("[^0-9]+"); // All but numeric
        if (regex.IsMatch(sender.Text))
        {
            error.Text = "Non numeric char";
            error.Visibility = Windows.UI.Xaml.Visibility.Visible;
            sender.Text = this.ViewModel.MyModel.Field1.ToString();
        }
        else
        {
            this.ViewModel.MyModel.Field1 = Convert.ToUInt32(sender.Text);
        }
    }

    private void field2_TextChanging(TextBox sender, TextBoxTextChangingEventArgs args)
    {
        var error = errorTextBlock;
        error.Visibility = Windows.UI.Xaml.Visibility.Collapsed;

        Regex regex = new Regex("[^0-9]+");
        if (regex.IsMatch(sender.Text))
        {
            error.Text = "Non numeric char";
            error.Visibility = Windows.UI.Xaml.Visibility.Visible;
            sender.Text = this.ViewModel.MyModel.Field2.ToString();
        }
        else
        {
            this.ViewModel.MyModel.Field2 = Convert.ToUInt32(sender.Text);
        }
    }
}
```

Finally, my XAML:

```xml
<TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" x:Name="errorTextBlock" Text="" Visibility="Collapsed" />

<TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Text="Field 1" />
<TextBox Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" x:Name="field1" Text="{x:Bind ViewModel.MyModel.Field1, Mode=OneWay}" Loaded="InitField1" />
<TextBlock Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" Text="Field 2" />
<TextBox Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" x:Name="field2" Text="{x:Bind ViewModel.MyModel.Field2, Mode=OneWay}" Loaded="InitField2" />
```

At runtime, if I type a non numeric char in `field1`, the input is filtered, `field1` returns to its previous value without the screen "blinking" (that's why I use the `TextChanging` event and not the `TextChanged`). Perfect! But if I type a numeric char, `field1` is correctly updated (I can see that with breakpoint), but when `field2` is set, I got a native exception when `RaisedPropertyChanged` is called:
[image: exception]

I'm suspecting some kind of threading error, but I'm pretty new to this kind of development. Any idea? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Updated to use a separate 'Model' class**

Here's how you can create a text box that when a number (integer) is entered into it another text box shows the entered number multiplied by another number.

Here's the UI. Note the `Mode` used for each binding and the second textbox is readonly because that's just for display.

```xml
<StackPanel>
    <TextBlock Text="Value 1" />
     <TextBox Text="{x:Bind ViewModel.MyModel.Value1, Mode=TwoWay}" />
     <TextBlock Text="Value 2" />
     <TextBox Text="{x:Bind ViewModel.MyModel.Value2, Mode=OneWay}" IsReadOnly="True" />
</StackPanel>
```

On the page I declare my Model

```cs
public MyViewModel ViewModel { get; set; } = new MyViewModel();
```

My ViewModel is very simple

```cs
public class MyViewModel
{
    public MyModel MyModel { get; set; } = new MyModel();
}
```

The Model class contains the logic

```cs
public class MyModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string _value1;

    public string Value1
    {
        get { return _value1; }
        set
        {
            if (_value1 != value)
            {
                _value1 = value;

                // Cause the updated value to be displayed on the UI
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Value1));

                // Is the entered value a number (int)?
                int numericValue;
                if (int.TryParse(value, out numericValue))
                {
                    // It's a number so set the other value
                    // multiplied by the ratio
                    Value2 = (numericValue * 3).ToString();
                }
                else
                {
                    // A number wasn't entered so indicate this
                    Value2 = "NaN";
                }

                // Cause the updated value2 to be displayed
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Value2));
            }
        }
    }

    // We can use the automatic property here as don't need any logic
    // relating the getting or setting this property
    public string Value2 { get; set; }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

With the above, when a number is entered for Value1 then Value2 will show a number three times as much (because I've set the ratio of 3).

You may notice that if you try the above that the change doesn't happen immediately and Value2 is only updated when the focus leaves the Value1 text box. This is because, by default, the two-way binding is only updated when focus is lost. This can easily be changed though.

If instead of using the new `x:Bind` method of binding we use the traditional `Binding` method we can force the binding to be updated whenever we want. Say, when the text is changed.

Modify the TextBox declaration like this:

```xml
     <TextBox Text="{Binding ViewModel.Value1, Mode=TwoWay}" 
              TextChanged="TextBox_OnTextChanged" />
```

Note that the binding syntax is different and we've added an event.
The handler of the event is

```cs
private void TextBox_OnTextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var be = (sender as TextBox).GetBindingExpression(TextBox.TextProperty);
    be.UpdateSource();
}
```

This forces the binding to update but there's another change we must make as well.
With the `x:Bind` syntax it tries to bind to the page. With the older `Binding` syntax it binds to the DataContext of the page. To make these the same, update the page constructor like this

```cs
public MainPage()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
    this.DataContext = this;
}
```

Now the app will work again and Value2 will be updated after every key press in the Value1 text box.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response; I'll go step by step if it doesn't bother you: I tried the "classic" `Binding` and it does work quite well. For the `x:Bind`, I understand what you did in the ViewModel, but that means that my model is "gone"? Is it possible to put `Value1` and `Value2` in a model and make it works the same way? To me, it's my model that says "hey, Value2 MUST always be Value1 * 3", so it's a little bit confusing to see that logic in the ViewModel. Am I clear?

Comment: @benichka  updated to separate out the Model class as requested.

Comment: Thank you for the added details, I will try it. Still, I'm still a bit confused that in my model, my fields are `string` and not `int`. I probably don't understand the MVVM very well yet, but I thought that models must be independant from the view ? And in this scenario this is not the case (we're dealing with `string` instead of `int` to prevent an `argumentException`). I asked another question to get around that problem; apparently one of the only option is to use a converter.